# multiple sites Array AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

try this but keep getting an error within flashbuilder.

Original:

single site allowed.

```
var lock:SiteLock = new SiteLock(); 
lock.addSite("mysite.com", false);       
lock.allowLocalPlay(true);
addChild(lock);
```

this run without error.

Then I try this for multiple sites array.

```
var lock:SiteLock = new SiteLock(); 
lock.addSites("mysite.com", "mysite2.com", "mysite3.com", "mysite4.com", false);     
lock.allowLocalPlay(true);
addChild(lock);
```

But get a warning message:

3590: String used where a Boolean value was expected.  The expression will be type coerced to Boolean.

I've just run into another issue.

```
lock.addSites(false, "mysite.com", "mysite2.com", "mysite3.com", "mysite4.com");
```

Works alright and load mysite4.com without issue.

But when I try to open a url like mysite4-mysite.com this get blocked when it's included into th lock like:

lock.addSites(false, "mysite.com", "mysite2.com", "mysite3-mysite.org", "mysite4-myusite.com");

I think this is a issue with the Sitelock class: [Iam using this class here](http://tarunkhurana.net/utilities/otherswfs/slideshow/assets/portfolioprojects/work2/BubbleGame/utilities/skyboy/security/SiteLock.as)

all Help are greatfull appreciated.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lock.addSites(false, "mysite.com", "mysite2.com", "mysite3.com", "mysite4.com");
```

It's only my gues as I don't know what is the `SiteLock` class you are using. Can you post the code/link?

Also, do you need to add your `lock` to the display list?

Comment: Thanks for replied me.

I am using this class: http://tarunkhurana.net/utilities/otherswfs/slideshow/assets/portfolioprojects/work2/BubbleGame/utilities/skyboy/security/SiteLock.as

And yes Add the Lock to display will Fix a bug many obfuscated tools have, after obfuscated the source code, the Stage of _stage become nulled, and this will break the swf file.

Comment: Thanks for your edits.

This version of the code has fixed the flashbuilder issue.
many thanks for your help, much appreciated.